# Parsing a latex file in Perl

Tags: perl, latex

Apologies for the very basic question!

I just want to read in a latex file (so text basically) and output all the (say) theorems, which are always in the format

```
\begin{theorem}
some lines of latex
\end{theorem}
```

I always kind of figured Perl was the right language for this!

Of course, I only know very basic programming in C++ and Java, and virtually no Perl.

Nonetheless I can currently read in a text file, and process it line by line.

It seems the most basic way to do this is:

```
($string =~ /pattern/)
```

I started getting confused by then reading about control codes like ?,*+,$, etc.

Any simple references or links to get me started?

(I put this on here and not the Tex site, as it could be useful generally for reading text files, and not just LaTeX!)

Comment: So you're looking for a basic parsing tutorial in Perl?

Comment: @Gabe, yes that would be good. This is just for practicality purposes only, so if someone tells me this is hard I probably will just keep doing it by hand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on a Unix-y machine (this includes Macs), for a task this small you should reach for `sed` first:

```
$ sed -ne '/^\\begin{theorem}$/,/^\\end{theorem}$/p' doc.tex
```

If you're on Windows, though, you don't get `sed` bundled with the OS, and perl is rather easier to install AIUI, so here's the equivalent:

```
> perl -ne 'print if /^\\begin\{theorem\}$/.../^\\end\{theorem\}$/;' doc.tex
```

You may notice a distinct resemblance between these two commands.  That's not an accident; Perl took ideas from many of the older Unix text-munging utilities, `sed` included.

Comment: Quick comment, years later: these extract also the `\begin{theorem}`
and `\end{theorem}` lines. How can we capture the contents only? Also, how to make that perl one-liner part of a code? Changing the `...` by `(.*)` did not work for me.

Comment: @RafaelSantos You should ask a new question or questions about these things.  You could then, for instance, explain more clearly what you mean by "part of a code".

Comment: @zwol Sorry! By "part of a code" I mean part of a Perl application, instead of a perl one-liner. I've discovered that `if ($contents =~ /\\begin\{theorem\}(.*?)\\end\{theorem\}/s)   {    $thetheorem = $1;    }` works for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the pattern 
    \begin{theorem}(.*)\end{theorem}

and then your theorem will be in variable $1 after you do the matching.

Note: I am assuming the most basic structure here. If theorem can be multi-line then I can give you the better solution.

Comment: I don't know if this works, the theorem can be multiline - I will edit the original question to show that it could be

Comment: You'll want to use a non-greedy capture: `(.+?)`